# nested linq to XML query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

How can I get LINQ to loop the nested winning branch? I want to loop the `sum_sweeden` and `sum_japan` fields.

This is my XML structure:

```
<TheAPI>
  <TheResult>
    <command>booksResults</command>
  </TheResult>
  <TheData>
    <books>
      <book id="101495">
        <coupon_close_date>1366030400</coupon_close_date>
        <coupon_local_close_date>1366012400</coupon_local_close_date>
        <book_status id="1">Published</book_status>
        <book_details>
          <book_detail>
            <author>bnvbnvb</author>
            <publisher>nnbnbn</publisher>           
          </book_detail>
        </book_details>
        <deals_breakdowns>
          <deal_breakdown id="1">
            <winning deal="5">
              <sum_sweeden>715.00</sum_sweeden>
              <sum_japan>715.00</sum_japan>
            </winning>
          </deal_breakdown>
          <deal_breakdown id="2">
            <winning>
              <sum_sweeden>100.00</sum_sweeden>
              <sum_japan>100.00</sum_japan>
            </winning>
          </deal_breakdown>
        </deals_breakdowns>
      </book>
      <book id="101417">
        <coupon_close_date>1387684800</coupon_close_date>
        <coupon_local_close_date>1387666800</coupon_local_close_date>
        <book_status id="1">Published</book_status>
        <book_details>
          <book_detail>
            <author>mn xccx cvx</author>
            <publisher>hjgh hg jghjg</publisher>         
          </book_detail>
        </book_details>
        <deals_breakdowns>
          <deal_breakdown id="1">
            <winning>0</winning>
          </deal_breakdown>
          <deal_breakdown id="2">
            <winning>
              <sum_sweeden >100</sum_sweeden>
              <sum_japan >100</sum_japan>
            </winning>
          </deal_breakdown>
        </deals_breakdowns>
      </book>
  </TheData>
</TheAPI>
```

I was able successfully to loop all the `book` with LINQ:

```
public class ResultsBookData
{
    public decimal couponCloseDate { get; set; }
    public decimal SumSweeden { get; set; }
    public int BookStatusId { get; set; }
    public string BookStatus { get; set; }
    public string Author { get; set; }
    public string Publisher { get; set; }
    public decimal SumJapan { get; set; }              
}

var result = (from node in books.Elements("book")
              select new ResultsBookData()
              {
                  couponCloseDate = node.SafeValueAsInt("coupon_close_date"),
                  SumSweeden = node.SafeValueAsInt("sum_sweeden"),
                  BookStatusId = node.SafeAttAsInt("book_status", "id"),
                  BookStatus = node.SafeValueAsString("book_status"),
                  Author = node.Element("book_details").HasElements ? node.Element("book_details").Element("book_detail").Element("author").Value : null,
                  Publisher = node.Element("book_details").HasElements ? node.Element("book_details").Element("book_detail").Element("publisher").Value : null,      
                  SumSweeden = node.Element("deals_breakdowns").Element("deals_breakdown").Element("winning").SafeValueAsDecimal("sum_sweeden"),      
                  SumJapan = node.Element("deals_breakdowns").Element("deals_breakdown").Element("winning").SafeValueAsDecimal("sum_japan"),
              }).ToList()
```

Comment: What do you mean loop? You can't "loop" with LINQ but you can loop the results. Can you please let us know what is the end result you need.

Comment: Are you consuming an API? If so, why not use xml serialization instead?

Comment: Side note - you don't have closing `</books>` tag here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First - you have several `<deals_breakdown>` elements in `<deals_breakdowns>`. So, you need to select all of them with `Elements("deals_breakdown")`. Second - you need to aggregate (summarize) `<sum_sweeden>` element values, because you have `SumSweeden` property which expects single decimal value, not collection of decimals:

```
SumSweeden = node.Element("deals_breakdowns")
                 .Elements("deals_breakdown")
                 .Sum(b => b.Element("winning")
                            .SafeValueAsDecimal("sum_sweeden")),
```

Also keep in mind, that you can safely cast elements to strings or some nullable types (bool, int, decimal). With this in mind you can get rid of your custom extension methods and use following query:

```
from book in books.Elements("book")
let bookStatus = book.Element("book_status")
let bookDetail = book.Elements("book_details").Elements("book_detail").FirstOrDefault()
let winnings = book.Element("deals_breakdowns").Elements("deal_breakdown").Elements("winning")
select new ResultsBookData()
{
    couponCloseDate = (int)book.Element("coupon_close_date"),
    BookStatusId = (int)bookStatus.Attribute("id"),
    BookStatus = (string)bookStatus,
    Author = bookDetail == null ? null : (string)bookDetail.Element("author"),
    Publisher = bookDetail == null ? null : (string)bookDetail.Element("publisher"),
    SumSweeden = winnings.Sum(w => (decimal?)w.Element("sum_sweeden") ?? 0),
    SumJapan = winnings.Sum(w => (decimal?)w.Element("sum_japan") ?? 0)
}
```

Result:

```
{
   couponCloseDate: 1366030400.0,
   SumSweeden: 815.00,
   BookStatusId: 1,
   BookStatus: "Published",
   Author: "bnvbnvb",
   Publisher: "nnbnbn",
   SumJapan: 815.00      
},
{
   couponCloseDate: 1387684800.0,
   SumSweeden: 100.0,
   BookStatusId: 1,
   BookStatus: "Published",
   Author: "mn xccx cvx",
   Publisher: "hjgh hg jghjg",
   SumJapan: 100.0
}
```

Comment: `SafeValueAsDecimal`?

Comment: @JohnSaunders I believe that is custom extension

Comment: The OP may know that, but none of the other readers of this question will know that.